# Force shell command to return

Tags: shell

I'm running a command (not part of the standard distro) that sometimes does not return the cursor. That is, I have to press enter myself.

The issue is that if I want to do it from a C++ program, the function system may not return.

Is there an alternative to run the program in background, and force it to return?

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't return"? Is it possible that it just does not end with a newline? If the application is really waiting for input (I doubt it), try to feed it null `< /dev/null` or if this doesn't work, you can also try pipe `yes` into it. But do check first if it is actually not terminating.

Comment: How would you determine whether the command returns? Do you want to systematically run it in the background? Or wait for a timeout? And what does this have to do with pressing enter — does the command wait for input? Your question is hard to understand and different people are interpreting in different ways. Please clarify it. Write an example of what you're doing, copy-paste the code and the terminal transcript and describe what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the PID of your running process you can do what you want like this.

#### Example

In *terminal #1:* Your fake process that's hanging:

```
$ cat
```

In *terminal #2:* Get the PID of this process:

```
$ pidof cat
1243
```

Send some input to this PID's STDIN:

```
$ echo xxx > /proc/1243/fd/0
$
```

Now *back in terminal #1:* The `cat` command now shows the following output:

```
$ cat 
xxx
```

You can combine the `echo` + `pidof` into one command:

```
$ echo xxx > /proc/$(pidof cat)/fd/0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pipe `echo` after it:

```
mycommand <args> | echo
```

That should force it to return to the prompt after the execution.

Comment: it doesn't work. I still have to hit enter

Answer (score -2):

Can you do this?

```
mycommand &
```